# How to implement a linked list for a flappy bird program in my class. Now I'm getting errors that "cannot be resolved to a field"

Tags: java, linked-list, variable-assignment

I have a model, view, and tube class and I don't know what's going on.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

class Model
{
    Bird bird;
    Random r = new Random();
    LinkedList<Tube> tubes;


    Model() {

        this.bird = new Bird();
        this.tubes = new LinkedList<Tube>();
        tubes.add(new Tube(r));
    }

    public void update() {
        this.bird.update();
        //this.tube.setPosition();
        //this.tube.update();
        ListIterator<Tube> tIterator = tubes.listIterator();
        while (tIterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("Another Tube");
        }

    }

    public void onClick(int x, int y) {
        this.bird.setDestination();
        this.bird.flap();
    }
}
```

This class below is where I get the error.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;

class View extends JPanel {
    Model model;
    Image bird_image;
    Image bird_image_flap;
    Image tube_image;
    Image tube_image_down;

    View(Model m) throws IOException {
        this.model = m;
        this.bird_image = ImageIO.read(new File("bird1.png"));
        this.bird_image_flap = ImageIO.read(new File("bird2.png"));
        this.tube_image = ImageIO.read(new File("tube_up.png"));
        this.tube_image_down = ImageIO.read(new File("tube_down.png")); 
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        if(this.model.bird.flapped){
            g.drawImage(this.bird_image_flap, this.model.bird.x, this.model.bird.y, null);
        } else {
            g.drawImage(this.bird_image, this.model.bird.x, this.model.bird.y, null);
        }   

        if(this.model.tubes.isItUp){
            g.drawImage(this.tube_image, this.model.tubes.tube_x, this.model.tubes.tube_y, null);

        } else {
            g.drawImage(this.tube_image_down, this.model.tubes.tube_x, this.model.tubes.tube_y - 400, null);

        }

    }
}
```

Multiple markers at line 32 down. One is the 'tube cannot be resolved or is not a field'. Another is 'isItUp cannot be resolved or is not a field'
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is this line, right?
    if(this.model.tubes.isItUp){
The field "tubes" on the "model" variable is of type "LinkedList" so I doubt it has a field "isItUp".  Where is the "isItUp" field you are trying to use?  Is it on a Tube object?  If so, then you need to get the relevant instance from the list (e.g. this.model.tubes.elementAt(0).isItUp).